# how does the ApplicationController class work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, static-pages

In rails if you were to render static pages you would use a class like below:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
  def about
  end
end
```

how does the ApplicationController process these functions so as to produce a get request? And what is the difference between the function processing and when the functions are named after HTTP verbs and they route accordingly?

Comment: May be you should look into this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: ok, so i guess my question is: how does inheriting from a class give these functions functionality? Because I'm struggling to visualise how these functions actually do anything

Comment: Actions, by default, render a template in the app/views directory corresponding to the name of the controller and action after executing code in the action. For example, the index action of the PostsController would render the template app/views/posts/index.html.erb by default after populating the @posts instance variable.See this line in the line

Comment: what is the methodology behind that? i.e. the logic of the ApplicationController. Although, since ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::base, what is the logic of the ActionController::base class that does this? i.e is it using method_missing? something else? where can I find out about this?